# In EntityFramework, How can I work on data in the {get; set;} before saving it

Tags: entity-framework-6, poco

I am using EntityFramework, CodeFirst, with POCO classes. I want to work on data in the properties, so, instead of the short version i.e. {get;set;} am using the long version. This way, I believed I could save / retrieve after/ before I worked on the data. I was under the impression that both the long and short versions for the properties get/setters would work. Data is getting saved but not the way I want... i.e. original data gets saved, not my modified version.

I have a simple class Person as follows

```
Public Class Person
{ 
    public long Id {get;set;}

    string _fName;
    public string FName
    {
         get 
         {
            return Decrypt(_fName); //Where Decrypt decrypts the value
         }
         set
         {
            _fName = Encrypt(value); //Where Encrypt encrypts the value
         }
    }
}
```

However, this does not work. FName does not save the Encrypted value, but rather original value is saved.

Then I tried...

```
Public Class Person
{ 
    public long Id {get;set;}

    string _fName;
    public string FName
    {
         get 
         {
            return Decrypt(_fName); //Where Decrypt decrypts the value
         }
         set
         {
            _fName = Encrypt(value); //Where Encrypt encrypts the value
            value = _fName; //Works up to here... but FName is unaffected.
         }
    }
}
```

It seems, EntityFramework is feeding the value directly into FName. I would like to be able to work on this value but would rather want to avoid the complication of overriding the SaveChanges event.

How can I cause EntityFramework to save the _fName value as shown above, which is encrypted?

Comment: Did you try without calling Decrypt/Encrypt to be sure this is not the problem?

Comment: You shouldn't put business logic into storage object property. EF use the same `set` and `get` methods when loading and saving data from/to db. Let say the data is encrypted in db. When EF loads your object, it will call `set`, and now the data will be double encrypted. Or let say you populate a new object and use a setter passing raw data. When EF creates Iinsert command, it calls `get` and of course gets the decrypted data.

Comment: @hugorgor. Yes. The problem is FName is NOT storing the data that is in _fName. You can try a simple example where Decrypt changes the value of _fName and you will find that the original value entered will be saved.

Comment: @IvanStoev. Thanks, but is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: if @IvanStoev is right, you should use data entities and domain entities.  Where you copy all values (and encrypt) from/to when saving/loading entities from database.

Comment: Yes... but not elegant.

Comment: Well, you can use two properties - one mapped and used by EF to load/persist data (the setter could be private to make sure it's not called by external code) and one unmapped containing the current logic. And make sure you don't access unmapped property in LINQ to Entities queries.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev. Thank you Ivan. I am working on a similar way around. I am a bit surprised that EF does not pick up the value from the Getter/Setter. I guess I will just intercept the value at ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized / ObjectContext.SavingChanges (probably the cleanest way.)